# Extracting email address, first name and last name from multiple PDF files within a folder

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction, pdfminer

I am trying to extract the following information from all PDF files within a folder, the PDF files are CV's: Email Address, First Name, Last Name for a work project.

I have successfully managed to extract Email Addresses using this code:

```
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage

import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import os

import re

working_directory = './folder'

file_list = []   # define file_list to save all dxf files
email_list = {}   # define file_list to save all dxf files
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(working_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            file_list.append(file)
            
for input_file in file_list:
    
    pagenums = set()
    
    output = StringIO()
    
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
    
    infile = open('./folder/' + input_file, 'rb')
    
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    
    infile.close()
    
    converter.close()
    
    text = output.getvalue()
    
    output.close()
    
    match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[a-z0-9\.-]+', text)
    
    try:
        email = match.group(0)
    except AttributeError:
        email = match
        
    if email is None:
        pass
    else:
        email_list.update({input_file: email})
        print(email_list[input_file])
    
email_list
```

But have trouble extracting First and Last Names, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think it would be better to specify the type of data you are trying to deal with.

Comment: If you believe that all PDFs are created in the same way, you are mistaken. This is really true if you are processing PDFs created by many applications. I can assure you that I can find documents you cannot process and so you will never find a complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find email information because there is logic behind it

```
match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[a-z0-9\.-]+', text)
```

But also you have to figure out a logic to find out first and last names of your PDF files.

Maybe an specific field after `Dear,` for example

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am looking for a way to yield 2 or preferably 3 variables from 1 CV, that is what I am having trouble with, I think I figured out a logic to finding the name. So that the output is e.g.: email: asdf@gmail.com, first name: John, last name: Doe. I am quite new to programming so there is probably an answer that is obvious to someone more experienced, but unfortunately I could not figure it out.